# sum function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I create a simple Visual Studio project and add JavaScript and HTML items to it, I seem to have access to all built in functions, such as `indexOf()`, `search()`, `slice()`, `range()`, etc...

However, when I try to use the `sum()` function (e.g. `console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));`) I get the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined

Putting this message within double quotes and adding the JavaScript keyword in Google did not bring up a webpage that tells me what I am missing, hence this basic question here.

Am I missing something like a library that `sum` is included in? What am I doing wrong that only this particular function is not recognized?

Comment: `sum` is not a built in function. Hence the "undefined" error

Comment: There is no `sum()` funtion in Javascript....

Comment: Sum is not a native function in JS

Comment: And there's no `range` either.

Comment: [Math.js has a sum()](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/sum.html) Is this what your after? TBH though it could be anything

Comment: @Liam Oh my god why on earth would someone call a library almost the same like a built-in object!

Comment: Thanks all.  I took this snippet from the following online book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/00_intro.html

Comment: *"here is what the program could look like **if we happened to have** the convenient operations range and sum available"*. It doesn't say that they do, though that is very confusing.

Comment: My bad.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you want to learn Javascript stick to a good resource like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript. Or my favourite book https://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596101996 (possibly a bit long in the tooth but covers all the basics)

Comment: I will.  Many thanks.  One last thing: When I add `Math` and then a `.` there is no `sum` listed.  Is that how you meant I could use the `Math.js`?

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) js tutorials are not bad also.. You can play with the code and see what happens so its quite comfortable

Comment: Oh god, don't mention w3schools, you will get lynched. They **we're** notoriously inacurate and annoyed a lot of people by associating themselves with the W3C (nothing to do with the W3C FYI). They have improved in recent times though...

Comment: No, you need to include the math library. Do what @JaqenH'ghar has said to do

Comment: @Liam Yes you are right, they are not related in any way and the name is confusing. Though for starting up with something its quite nice because you can edit the code online and see changes. Learning by reading only is less efficient and their Try it Yourself makes things easy. Like you said though MDN is far more accurate, but I think it will be harder to start with

Comment: @Liam It's me again. Do you know of a tutorial that concentrates on solving examples of real-world problems, rather than exploring the language and its features and mechanisms in such great and fine detail? These refs go through millions of features and details that is just impossible to exhaust. I have learned the basic features and mechanics of the language, so I would like to start small in applying it to everyday problems. For example, tutorials on how to make a GUI application to manage a school reg system or a part of a supermarket or any little project? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in `sum()` function in Javascript.

You can create one easily with [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function sum(arr) {
   return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
   }, 0);
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(sum(numbers));
```

Or use `reduce()` as a oneliner:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

var totalSum = numbers.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);

console.log(totalSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of it, here's a nice ES6 version:

```
const sum = (arr=[]) => arr.reduce((total, val) => total + val);
```